# Finding $\sup$ and $\inf$ of a set described by a monotone sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence and let $X=\{a_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, suppose also that $a_n\rightarrow l\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $a_n\leq a_{n+1} \ \forall n\geq n_0$ In order to determine $\sup(X), \inf(X)$, my reasoning was the following: since the sequence is increasing for $n\geq n_0$, we have $a_0>a_1>a_2>...>a_{n_0}\leq a_{n_0+1}\leq...\leq l$, so if $a_0\geq l$ we have $\max(X)=\sup(X)=a_0$ (otherwise, $l=\sup(X)$ and we have to determine if $\max(X)$ exists), and $\min(X)=a_{n_0}$

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is incorrect. It holds only if it is also known that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for $n < n_0$ - which is not necessary (as per your problem statement).

$\sup X$ is given by
$$\sup X = \max\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n_0-1}, l\}$$
Note that the sequence being increasing for $n\ge n_0$ does not guarantee that it is decreasing for $n < n_0$. For example, consider $n_0 = 3$ and $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 3$, and $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\ge 3$. In this case, $\sup X = 3$.

Similarly, you can check that
$$\inf X = \min\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n_0-1}, a_{n_0}\}$$

Comment: Sorry, maybe I had to specify that my sequence is increasing only if $n \geq n_0$, I suppose this changes what you said

Comment: You had to specify both conditions, yes. If that's the case, then you're right. Otherwise, my answer clarifies it. Feel free to upvote/accept if you found this helpful in answering your question!

Comment: Copy, thanks! You are right, I had to specify but I forgot to do so

Comment: By the way, $\max$ and $\min$ don't really make sense for infinite sets, that's why we use $\sup$ and $\inf$. You might want to fix your notation! @Gabriele